# If a camera has two lenses, where is the focal plane? In the sensor or in the second lens?

Tags: lens, focal-length, optics

For example, this exercises asks where is the focal plane. Is in the sensor or in the second lens?

[image]

Comment: Is that camera supposed to be a TLR type camera? (Twin lens reflex)

Comment: Nope. Just a regular reflex camera.

Comment: So then where are you getting a second lens from?

Comment: @Corey The first lens is the one farther right, the second one is farther left.

Comment: @twalberg So, if i think of those two lenses as a single compound lens the focal plane would be on the sensor. Correct?

Comment: What is the source of this image?

Comment: Your diagram shows only a single lens, so this whole question makes no sense.  It does show two *elements* in the single lens, but that's not what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The focal plane is of course at the sensor when the mirror is up.

In a SLR, and the mirror is down, the focal plane is on the ground glass screen below the pentaprism (which is at the same distance as the sensor).  The eye piece lens focuses on that ground glass screen image.

Answer (score 2):

From a comment:

> So, if i think of those two lenses as a single compound lens the focal plane would be on the sensor. Correct?

Yes — well, actually, a *complex* lens, not merely a *compound* lens. A complex lens includes several *groups* of simple and compound lenses. In any case, the end result is an optical system which (when correctly adjusted) focuses on the sensor.

Otherwise... none of our gear would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

We can construct a camera lens using just one lens (element). This lens acts just like a movie or slide projector in that it projects an image of the outside world onto the surface of an image sensor (or film), located inside and at the rear of the camera body. The resulting image will be besmirched because all lenses suffer from image distorting aberrations. There are 7 major aberrations, you can look them up to discover how they misrepresent the image.  1 Spherical Aberration 2. Coma 3. Astigmatism 4 Curvature of field 5. Distortion 6. Transverse Chromatic 7. Longitudinal Chromatic.

The lens maker is tasked to design the camera optical system in such a way that all seven are mitigated. The best that can be achieved is mitigation as residual aberrations remain regardless of how hard the lens maker tries to remove.

To accomplish the lens maker adds additional lens elements. Some are positive in power (convex). Some are negated in power (concave). Some use dense glass and some a lighter as to density. The scheme is, some elements present the opposite aberration as compared to its neighbor. Combining two elements with opposite aberrations will mediate.

Now the power of a lens is expresses by stating it’s focal length. This is measurement taken when the lens system is imaging a far distant subject. The distance lens to sharply focused image is taken. This distance, usually expressed in millimeters is the focal length. The focal plane is the flat surface of the image sensor or film.